# Hide JPanel by clicking outside of it

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have a JLayeredPane with a Checkbox on the Default_Layer.
By checking it, a Panel shows up on the Palette_Layer.
All of that works fine.

I just want to know how to hide the Panel again by clicking outside of it, without unchecking the Checkbox.

Comment: MouseListener on the JLayeredPane, with `myPanel.setVisible(false)` followed by `.repaint()` on the JLayeredPane. Also, give the JPanel itself a MouseListener to absorb mouse presses.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Thanks. That solves my problem